# Uniswap V3: how to get maximum NFT Position token Id?

Tags: tokens, ethers.js, uniswap, defi, uniswapv3

I want to get the maximum NFT Position ID to make calculation on a Pool over all NFT Positions. How to do that ? Can I do that using the blockchain ?